# Splash Screen causes null pointer in Main Activity with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, splash-screen

I'm trying to add a Splash Screen to my Android Rss Reader application, so that i can check network connectivity and determine which screen the user sees first, depending on connectivity.

Without the SplashScreen, the MainActivity.java works fine, but when I set SplashScreenActivity as the launcher within the Manifest, the Asynctask within MainActivity throws a null pointer when it runs. Does anybody know what the reason for this might be?

Thanks for your time!

SplashScreenActivity.java

```
enter code here

public class SplashScreenActivity extends MainActivity {

boolean alreadyExecuted = false;
private static String TAG = SplashScreenActivity.class.getName();
private static long SLEEP_TIME = 5;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    // Removes title bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);    // Removes notification bar
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    // Start timer and launch main activity
    IntentLauncher launcher = new IntentLauncher();
    launcher.start();
}

private class IntentLauncher extends Thread {
    @Override
    /**
     * Sleep for some time and than start new activity.
     */
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Sleeping
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME*2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        //If this method is called once, set boolean alreadyExecuted to true
        if(!alreadyExecuted)
        {
            Check();
            alreadyExecuted=true;
        }

    }

}

//Check if network is available. If so go to MainActivity screen, which requires internet
//If not, go to MyFeeds screen
public void Check()
{
    if (NetworkCheck.getInstance(this).isOnline()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();


    }
    else
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MyFeedsScreen.class);
        SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();
    }
}}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MainActivity local;
private DatabaseHandler db;


//Method to create main application view
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //set view
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    //**************************create a button to move to the user's saved feeds screen*****************************

    Button myFeedsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myFeedsButton);
    myFeedsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyFeedsScreen.class));
        }
    });

  //*****************************************************************************************************************

    //Create new instance of database handler
    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    //set local ref to this activity
    local = this;

    //Calls the doInBackground method
    GetRSSDataTask task = new GetRSSDataTask();

    //start download Rss task - execute method calls the
    task.execute("http://pitchfork.com/rss/reviews/best/albums/");

    //debug thread name
    Log.d("RssReaderApp", Thread.currentThread().getName());
}

//*******************************************************************************************************************

private class GetRSSDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RssItem>>
{
    @Override
    protected List<RssItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {

        //debug task thread name
        Log.d("RssReaderApp", Thread.currentThread().getName());

        try {
            //create a new reader
            RssReader rssReader = new RssReader(urls[0]);

            //Parse RSS, get items
            return rssReader.getItems();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("RssReaderApp", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;

    }//doInBackground


    //is invoked on UI thread after background tasks are complete.
    // Results of background task are passed here as a parameter
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> result)
    {
        //Gets listview from main.xml
        final ListView listItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMainView);

        //Creates a new list adapter - displays an array of strings in listview
        ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(local, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
        //Set list adapter for listView
        listItems.setAdapter(adapter);

        //OnItemClick listener set to allow user to access content from title
        listItems.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(result, local));



        //*******************************LONG CLICK FUNCTIONALITY******************************************
        //Set new long click listener which should allow item to be stored to db
        listItems.setLongClickable(true);
        listItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                try {

                    db.open();
                    RssItem fromList = (RssItem) listItems.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    RssItem item = new RssItem();

                    item.title = fromList.title;
                    item._id = fromList._id;
                    //item.completeTextLink = fromList.completeTextLink;
                    //item.mainBody = fromList.mainBody;
                    item.link = fromList.link;
                    item.description = fromList.description;
                   // item.page = fromList.page;

                    db.insertRssItem(item);

                    db.close();


                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item saved in My Feeds!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;


            }
        });

        }//onPostExecute
    }//getRssTaskClass}//class
```

Android Manifest, with SplashScreenActvity, rather than MainActivity now set as launcher:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application

    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="com.example.rory.RssReaderApp.MainActivity">


    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.rory.RssReaderApp.MyFeedsScreen"></activity>

    <activity android:name=".DetailsActivity"></activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.rory.RssReaderApp.SplashScreenActivity">
        android:icon="@drawable/newspaper"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>


</application>
```

LogCat error:

```
08-19 02:23:52.467  15372-15372/com.example.rory.readerapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rory.readerapp, PID: 15372
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.rory.RssReaderApp.MainActivity$GetRSSDataTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:113)
        at com.example.rory.RssReaderApp.MainActivity$GetRSSDataTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:79)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Comment: LogCat error? Show us the error

Comment: By the looks of your logcat error...for some reason your listview is coming up null and you are setting an adapter to a null object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem! I had accidentally made the SplashScreenActivity.java class extend MainActivity rather than Activity.

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing your MainActivity in your `onPostExecute` when setting your `listItems`.

```
 final ListView listItems = (ListView) local.findViewById(R.id.listMainView);
```

Comment: there is no reason whatsoever why this would behave any differently.